# Spring - RestController dispatcher

Tags: spring, api, rest, http, controller

in order to get my basic rest-api (only GET) working, i created this setup:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>app</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

next i have this api controller:

```
package packagename.controller.api;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import packagename.model.Home;

@RestController
public class HomeApiController {

    @RequestMapping("/api/home")
    public Home greeting() {
        return new Home(1, "asdas");
    }

}
```

and the actual Home model:

```
package packagename.model;

public class Home {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Home(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

When i create the war file and put it into the webapps folder of my tomcat server, i open "localhost:8080/webappname/api/home".

Next i get 404-error, but i have no idea why.

Anybody could help me with this setup?
Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: You've mixed spring boot with traditional web application. RestController is enough and there is no need to specify a web.xml. What you need is removing web.xml and add dependency  `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` and marking it as `provided` and change `packaging` to `war` and configuring war plugin continue without a web.xml.

Comment: Yes you can. Please use `/**` instead of `/` as your `url-pattern ` in servlet setting.

Comment: i added this change, but still 404 remaining..

Answer (score 0):

You've mixed spring boot with traditional web application.

RestController is enough and there is no need to specify a web.xml.

What you need is removing web.xml and add dependency  `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` and marking it as `provided` and change `packaging` to `war` and configuring war plugin continue without a web.xml.

And document http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging could help.

Please let me know if any question.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer, but there is a webapplication as well which needs web.xml... is there any possibility so they can both(web app and RestApi) coexist ? greetings

Comment: Yes you can. Please have a loot at this project: https://github.com/soiff-spring/spring-mvc-example .

Comment: Why do you think there's boot involved here at all? They've clearly stated they created a war and deployed to tomcat.

Comment: My point is the component you are trying to integrate not the target application. Of course I know you can use it in a war project. Additionally,  they are two methods available and I posted my suggestion, and what can I do for you?